# Why do I get the error "Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, unsafe

Why do I get the following error?

> Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe"?

I work in C# and Visual Studio 2008 for programming on Windows CE.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezb5hwx9%28VS.80%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can seem to get msbuild to build unsafe code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992374/i-can-seem-to-get-msbuild-to-build-unsafe-code-blocks)

Answer (score 300, accepted):

To use unsafe code blocks, the project has to be compiled with the /unsafe switch on.

Open the properties for the project, go to the `Build` tab and check the `Allow unsafe code` checkbox.

Comment: I must say, even though that does enable the build to compile, it still doesn't allow it to get published to the web :/

Comment: @Nick: Yes, if you publish code to be compiled dynamically, then the project settings doesn't apply. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567197/asp-net-publish-web-application-with-unsafe-code

Comment: Note that the settings might differ between Debug and Release compile. This just cost me 20 minutes of my life.

Comment: You may have to change the build configuration from Debug to Release for different type of builds

Answer (score 135):

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Unsafe screenshot]

ََََََََ

Comment: Important: Also be aware that this screenshot is for "Configuration: Active (Debug)". You'll probably also need to change it for "Release", since that's most likely what you're publishing.

Answer (score 4):

Probably because you're using unsafe code.

Are you doing something with pointers or unmanaged assemblies somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

Search your code for `unsafe` blocks or statements. These are only valid is compiled with `/unsafe`.

Answer (score 4):

To use unsafe code blocks, open the properties for the project, go to the *Build* tab and check the *Allow unsafe code* checkbox, then compile and run.

```
class myclass
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         unsafe
         {
             int iData = 10;
             int* pData = &iData;
             Console.WriteLine("Data is " + iData);
             Console.WriteLine("Address is " + (int)pData);
         }
     }
}
```

Output:

```
Data is 10
Address is 1831848
```

Answer (score 4):

Can also add `AllowUnsafeBlocks` tag to `PropertyGroup` directly in .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1; net472</TargetFrameworks>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

For everybody who uses Rider you have to select your project>Right Click>Properties>Configurations Then select Debug and Release and check "Allow unsafe code" for **both**.[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I add this Line to Project file
`<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>`
it work for me.