# What's the difference between publishing and building an Mvc 4 app with respect to unsafe code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, publishing, unsafe

I have an asp.net mvc 4 app that references a c# project which uses the unsafe keyword and this is allowed for in the project properties. The problem is when I publish the web app and I get the unsafe errors. In another post ([Publish web application with unsafe code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567197/)), someone says there is a difference between publishing and building and the app's web.config file needs to be edited.

I added in the following to the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
<!--Some other configuration code-->
 <system.codedom>
 <compilers>
   <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" compilerOptions="/unsafe"  type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
 </compilers>
 </system.codedom>
<!--Some other configuration code-->
</configuration>
```

But this didn't work (also didn't work for the other poster). Rather than restate his question, my question is:

**Given there's a difference between publishing and building for unsafe code, how can I check if this web.config change is being picked up correctly?**

**In addition, I've using IIS8 Express. Is there additional configuration I need to do in IIS to allow unsafe code to be published perhaps?**

Possibly relevant: Before referencing the unsafe code project I was able to build the web app and view the unpublished result in the browser by binding some url in IIS to that project. After referencing, I get an error when using the url. Running the debugger from visual studio is fine and so this makes me think that IIS is the culprit. I'm a novice though and really am grasping for ideas. Any help much appreciated.

(Windows 8, VS2012)

Comment: Is `/unsafe` actually *present* in the `Web.config` file that is in use when running the application in IIS?

Comment: I think so. The web.config file that is in the root of the web app folder has /unsafe. Is this the right place to look?

Comment: Are you precompiling when publishing? Also, could you wrap calls to the unsafe referenced library in `unsafe` blocks?

Comment: And this is the same folder, that is referenced within the <sites> tag in the IIS file applicationhost.config

Comment: I tried pre compiling just now without any difference. The unsafe code  is already written as: unsafe{my unsafe code}. I think this what you meant right?

Comment: Got it. I stupidly didn't mention that i'm running the app as x64. I had forgotten to make the changes to the publish settings when I changed this over. This fixes it. Your pre compile comment got me looking in the other settings. Thanks!!

Comment: To make this question useful to future visitors, please add the resolution as an answer and accept it.