# How to compile unsafe code in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

How to resolve this error in VS2012 "Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe”?  I am not compiling from the command-line so I cannot simply add /unsafe.  How can I compile unsafe code in VS2012?

Comment: The message even tells you which option to pass to the compiler -- `/unsafe`!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get the error "Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026410/why-do-i-get-the-error-unsafe-code-may-only-appear-if-compiling-with-unsafe)

Comment: You forget `vb.net` and `f#` tags.

Comment: @Soner And C++/CLI, for completeness.

Comment: @wudzik this question is regarding VS2008 or VS2010, but I was not able to resolve the problem in VS2012 because it does not contain the check box named "Allow unsafe code".

Comment: @ShilpaSoni I have VS 2012 and did what's [explained on that link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6771861/1169228). I can see the CheckBox just fine.

Comment: @Nolonar Is it because I have Microsoft VS express 2012?

Comment: what project type you're working with?

Comment: try this edit your *.csproj file in text editor navigate to PropertyGroup and add  AllowUnsafeBlocks then save it and restart VS. ex: `  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I just got the solution, Actually I was looking that option (Allow unsafe code) in website's properties. Now when I saw in project's properties I found the check box and my error got resolved.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Right click on your project. Select "Properties". Switch to the "Build" tab. Check "Allow unsafe code".

Comment: I was not able to resolve the problem in VS2012 because it does not contain the check box named "Allow unsafe code"

Comment: I'm sitting right in front of it. My version does have it. Maybe your version does not allow unsafe code or you need to reinstall.

Comment: I just got the solution, Actually I was looking that option (Allow unsafe code) in website's properties. Now when I saw in project's properties I found the check box and my error got resolved.

Comment: @ShilpaSoni You should accept an answer; they both basically tell you to open the `Project > Properties`, which is how you solved your problem "by yourself".

Answer (score 7):

Open `project properties`, select `Build` tab and click on `Allow unsafe code`.

Comment: I was not able to resolve the problem in VS2012 because it does not contain the check box named "Allow unsafe code".