# Why PixelFormat is Format32bppArgb, but image have Format1bppIndexed

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have image, that have `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed` (view in windows explorer file properties).

But after load the file, seen `Format32bppArgb`:

```
string path = "cat.png";
using (var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(path))
{
    // bitmap.PixelFormat == Format32bppArgb, but must Format1bppIndexed 
}
```

what could be the problem?

*test image 1*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2HGH.png
*test image 2*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUgEy.png

**UPD**
Try to use constructor

```
//   useIcm:
//     true to use color correction for this System.Drawing.Bitmap; otherwise, false.
Bitmap(string filename, bool useIcm);
```

test image 1 loaded success, but test image 2 have `Format32bppArgb`

Comment: An image codec is not required to tell you anything about the pixel format of the file.  And the PNG codec is doing you a big favor here, 1bppIndexed is a very awkward format, like all indexed formats, basic image manipulation is not supported and converting it to the video adapter format is very slow.  No such problem with 32bppArgb.

Comment: @HansPassant No, this one is an actual bug... it's related to the png having a palette with alpha masking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the .Net framework; it seems to have a problem with the way transparency works on paletted png images.

See, paletted png images are actually fully alpha-capable, on a palette level. The png file has a specific extra chunk (the "tRNS" chunk) that can be added to define the alpha of each palette entry. Somehow, when encountering this, the .Net framework applies this alpha correctly, but then insists on treating the image as 32bppARGB.

This is very strange, because it completely supports alpha on the palette in exactly that way, *and* can in fact *save* files like that without any issue.

What is especially odd is that the file you have there doesn't actually *have* transparency on its palette; the "tRNS" chunk defines all palette entries as 100% opaque. But it seems just *having* the chunk is enough.

The workaround is to load the png into a byte array, read and cut out the "tRNS" chunk containing the transparency data so the .Net framework retains the indexed format, and, after loading the image from a stream created from the edited byte array, post-process the palette using the read "tRNS" data to apply the alpha.

The full code to do that is posted in this answer:

[A: Loading an indexed color image file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45100442/395685)

By the way, analysis of the png chunks showed that that second image is in fact a one-bit-per-pixel image, with a palette of *256 colours*. No idea how you managed that.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `Bitmap` constructor, it parses the image file and loads it into an object.  What you're seeing is not the `PixelFormat` of the file, but the `PixelFormat` of the object.  The constructor is converting the format to `Format32bppArgb` internally.

Comment: But i have other similar file, which PixelFormat == Format1bppIndexed after loading. How to force load with format of the file?

Answer (score 0):

It does not really matter what the pixel format of the original image is. It depends on the decoder whether it preserves the original pixel format. If you really want to convert a 2-color image to 1 bpp format, see the `ConvertPixelFormat` method in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824773/saving-transparent-png-as-transparent-gif/32826049#32826049).