# How can I get permission to write an unsafe code in ashx file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unsafe, ashx, ihttpasynchandler

How can I get permission to write an unsafe code in ashx file?
When I use unsafe code in asp i encounter the following error.

> unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650429/how-to-compile-unsafe-code-in-vs2012

Comment: minor formatting improvement

Comment: why do you want to do something "unsafe" in the first place? Maybe there's a better way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do

Comment: i have just one ashx file

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project. Select "Properties". Switch to the "Build" tab. Check "Allow unsafe code".