# I can seem to get msbuild to build unsafe code blocks

Tags: c#, msbuild, unsafe

`msbuild` doesn't seem to allow me build `unsafe` blocks even though my `.csproj` specify:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

my build command is:

```
msbuild myProject.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /t:Clean,Build
```

Comment: You did not configure the project correctly, common mistake.  Use Project > Properties > Build tab.  Note the comboboxes at the top of the property page.  Change the one labeled "Configuration" to "Release".  Now tick the option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You showed that the property is set for the *Debug* configuration. One option is that it's missing for the *Release* configuration.

Also you specified the platform on the command line as `"Any CPU"` (with a space), while the build file requires `"AnyCPU"`. This might also cause it to not being picked up.

Comment: FYI, ensuring this was all correct did not help me.  The following answer did (adding /p:AllowUnsafe.... to the MSBuild command)

Comment: @BRebey: This would still indicate that your project configuration is wrong.

Answer (score 14):

I added `/p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true` to `MSBuild` command, as follow:

```
MSBuild some-project.csproj /p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true
```

If you are in VSTS, you could just include the `/p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true` in the parameter.

This works for me.