# Build fails in Visual Studio App Center for Xamarin iOS: Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe

Tags: c#, xamarin, msbuild, msbuild-task, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to build a Xamarin iOS app in Visual Studio App Center. The solution contains two projects. One is a Xamarin iOS project. The other is a bindings library project. The bindings library project is configured with the `Allow 'unsafe' code` option.

[image]

But the `Xamarin.iOS` build task in the App Center fails saying:

`Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe`

[image]

I'm able to build the solution locally without any issues.

Anybody an idea?

---

After trying different things I switched from the .csproj file to the .sln file in the build configuration.

[image]

Can somebody verify this?

Comment: Can you check if the setting is still checked if you switch to the `Release` configuration?

Comment: The setting is still checked when I switch to the `Release` config and it builds successfully on my machine but still fails in the App Center. :(

Comment: When I take a look at the `msbuild`call then the `/unsafe`switch is not passed.


`[command]/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5_4_1/bin/msbuild /Users/vsts/agent/2.127.0/work/1/s/ios-xamarin/App.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=iPhoneSimulator /t:Rebuild`


Maybe the `/unsafe` switch is not supported?

Comment: Local use of `msbuild` via terminal succeeds. Even without the `/unsafe` switch.

Comment: the unsafe parameter would be passed to the compiler, not to msbuild. the msbuild logic only uses the `AllowUnsafeBlocks` property defined in the csproj file to pass it on to the compiler. you can check the csproj file if this property is defined under any element with a `Condition` attribute that looks like it could affect the build.

Comment: when you say "local use", did you pass the same parameters? especially `/p:Configuration=Release`

Comment: Thank you for making clear that `msbuild` is using the `.csproj` content to pass things to the `csc`. I was not aware of it. When I say local I mean building on my local machine. This local build succeeds from Visual Studio and using `msbuild` via terminal. Even when using the `/p:Configuration=Release` argument.

Comment: @Luca could you solve your issue in the end? Running into the same problem ...

Comment: Yes it works now. I think switching to the solution in the build configuration did the trick. Before I referenced the .csproj file in the build config. After referencing the .sln file the build was successful.

Comment: Finally, I was also able to fix this problem by switching to the SLN file, and creating a new configuration mapping to build only the according csproj.
I spent some time on this together with AppCenter support, and the mentioned problem is a known issue there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/xamarin/ios/solution-configuration-mappings

Answer (score 3):

Probably you encounter the error like this when building in App Center:

`error CS0227: Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe`

Please try either building from `.sln` so that your PCL configuration will be honored or add `Release|iPhone` (or the one you're trying to build) configuration with `unsafe` enabled to the PCL/.NET Standard project.

Reason: when building from `.csproj` file, `msbuild` expects to have the same configuration names in all referenced projects, cause there is no possibility to know how to map iOS project configuration `Release|iPhone` to configurations in PCL project which normally do not have `*|iPhone` part in it.

Documentation reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/xamarin/ios/#312-building-from-the-project-file-csprojfsproj

Answer (score 0):

I had a xamarin.ios project that built locally with the 'allow unsafe code' boxes checked, but it gave the same error when I tried to build on AppCenter.

To get it to build successfully I added the AllowUnsafeBlocks as an Environment Variable then set it to true.

I was trying to figure out where to add it as an msbuild command as this person suggested
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50755461/7933361
and for me it worked as an environment variable. When I remove the environment variable the build fails
[image: build setup]